# Extract common lines from multiple text files and display original line numbers

Tags: shell, awk, grep

What I want?

1. Extract the common lines from n large files.
2. Append the original line numbers of each files.

Example:

File1.txt has the following content

```
apple
banana
cat
```

File2.txt has the following content

```
boy
girl
banana
apple
```

File3.txt has the following content

```
foo
apple
bar
```

The output should be a different file

```
1 3 2 apple
```

1, 3 and 2 in the output are the original line numbers of `File1.txt`, `File2.txt` and `File3.txt` where the common line `apple` exists

I have tried using `grep -nf File1.txt File2.txt File3.txt`, but it returns

```
File2.txt:3:apple
File3.txt:2:apple
```

Comment: Do any of those files contain repeated lines? Like, could *apple* for example, be found in a file twice?

Comment: what about `grep -nf <(grep -f <(grep -f file1.txt file2.txt) file3.txt) file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt`

Comment: @oguzismail No, they are unique. I have already removed the redundant lines.

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul It gave ```file1.txt:1:apple
file2.txt:3:apple
file3.txt:2:apple
```.I think your approach is better than my naive one which showed only the outputs of the last two files. However, I want the line numbers to be appended in a tab separated form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Associate each unique line with a space separated list of line numbers indicating where it is seen in each file in an array, and print these next to each other at the end if the line is found in all three files.

```
awk '{
  n[$0] = n[$0] FNR OFS
  c[$0]++
}
END {
  for (r in c)
    if (c[r] == 3)
      print n[r] r
}' file1 file2 file3
```

If the number of files is unknown, refer to [Ravinder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63595951/10248678), or just change the hardcoded **3** in the **END** block with **ARGC-1** as shown there.

Answer (score 3):

GNU awk specific approach that works with any number of files:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
BEGINFILE {
    nfiles++
}
{
    lines[$0][nfiles] = FNR
}
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
    for (line in lines) {
        if (length(lines[line]) == nfiles) {
            for (file = 1; file <= nfiles; file++)
                printf "%d\t", lines[line][file]
            print line
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```sh
$ ./showlines file[123].txt
1   3   2   apple
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, written and tested with GNU `awk`, one could make use of `ARGC` value which gives us total number of element passed to `awk` program.

```
awk '
{
  a[$0]=(a[$0]?a[$0] OFS:"")FNR
  count[$0]++
}
END{
  for(i in count){
    if(count[i]==(ARGC-1)){
       print i,a[i]
    }
  }
}
' file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

A perl solution

```
perl -ne '
  $h{$_} .= "$.\t";  # append current line number and tab character to value in a hash with key current line
  $. = 0 if eof;     # reset line number when end of file is reached
  END{
    while ( ($k,$v) = each %h ) { # loop over has entries
      if ( $v =~ y/\t// == 3 ) {  # if value contains 3 tabs
        print $v.$k               # print value concatenated with key
      }
    }
  }' file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```